# Bootstrap Responsive Navbar 2.3 - How to Vertically align logo and links

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less, navbar

Want logo and links in Bootstrap **navbar** vertically center aligned.

I'm close.  The following code results in logo aligned to bottom of navbar and links vertically center aligned. I think this has something to do with LESS and the brand, clearfix classes which of course I can't see in the compiled css.  I've search and many answers seem close, but no real answer yet.

```cs
        <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="navbar-inner clearfix">
                <a class="brand" href="#"><img class="logo" src="img/mylogo.png"></a> 
                <div class="container">

                   <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </a>

                    <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="nav pull-right">
                            <li>
                                <a class="nav-text" href="#about">About</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="nav-text" href="#pricing">Pricing</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="nav-text" href="/blog">Blog</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="nav-text" href="https://mysite.com">Support</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="nav-text" href="/settings">Settings</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="nav-text" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal">
                                    </i>Login</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS is:

```cs
root { 
    display: block;
}
/* add style here */
 body {
   padding-left: 0;
   padding-right: 0;
 }
 .navbar {
   height: 60px;
   opacity:0.8;
 }
 .navbar .navbar-inner {
   background: #ffffff;
   border: none;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 2px 0px #333333, 0px 1px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392);
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 2px 0px #333333, 0px 1px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392);
   -o-box-shadow: 0px 3px 2px 0px #333333, 0px 1px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392);
   box-shadow: 0px 3px 2px 0px #333333, 0px 1px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392);
   height: 60px;
   padding-left: 20px;
   padding-right: 20px;
   padding-top:10px;


 }
 .navbar .navbar-inner .responsive-container {


 }
 .nav-text {     
   font-family:"open sans";
   font-size: 16px;
   font-weight: bold;
   color: #000000;  
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, move the `.brand` class inside container. If your brand image has 80px height, then give 30px padding to the top and bottom of the class `'.navbar .nav > li > a`. Remove all other paddings, heights and margins that you have given to `.navbar`, `.navbar-inner` classes.

Here is the updated bootply http://bootply.com/63025

CSS:

```
/* add style here */
 body {
   padding-left: 0;
   padding-right: 0;
 }
 .navbar {
   opacity:0.8;
 }
 .navbar .navbar-inner {
   background: #ffffff;
   border: none;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 2px 0px #333333, 0px 1px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392);
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 2px 0px #333333, 0px 1px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392);
   -o-box-shadow: 0px 3px 2px 0px #333333, 0px 1px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392);
   box-shadow: 0px 3px 2px 0px #333333, 0px 1px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392);


 }
.navbar .nav > li > a {
      padding:30px 10px 30px
    }
```

HTML:

```
            <div class="container">
            <a class="brand" href="#"><img class="logo" src="img/mylogo.png"></a> 
               <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </a>

                <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav pull-right">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#about">About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#pricing">Pricing</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/blog">Blog</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="https://mysite.com">Support</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/settings">Settings</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal">
                                Login</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: what about green check mark, if this resolution fixed your issue?